# Count number of rows before first non-zero

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to count the number of rows before and including the the first non-zero per species x date. I have managed to import and sort data, and can return the value of the first non-zero row per site x date, but I cannot calculate the number of rows before the first non-zero. Ecologically, this analysis is trying to determine how many surveys one would need to do (species x date) to record our focal species (values).

I have tried to use the `tidyverse`/`dplyr` environment to do this, trying `summarise()` and `n()`, with little success. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Below is an example of data that I have been trying to write this code for:

```
test_df <- structure(list(site = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                               "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                               "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
                      Date = structure(c(17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 
                                         17318, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 
                                         17287, 17318, 17167, 17198, 
                                         17226, 17257, 17287, 17318), 
                                       class = "Date"), values = c(0,                                                                                                                        0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 50)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", 
                 .Names = c("site", "Date", "values"))
```

This is the code to return the value of the first non-zero row (by species x date):

```
test_df %>% 
  # Convert site to factor, so we can use complete later. 
  # We do this within group_by, because we want to operate by level of site
  group_by(site=factor(site)) %>% 
  # Remove all rows of variable if there aren't any rows with values==0
  filter(any(values==0)) %>% 
  # Remove all rows with values != 0
  filter(values != 0) %>% 
  # Keep the first row of each variable, after sorting by date
  # This gives us the first non-zero row
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  # Use complete to bring back a row for any level of variable that
  # didn't start with any rows with values==0
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(site)
```

Instead of the resulting table looking like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  site  Date       values
  <fct> <date>      <dbl>
1 a     2017-04-01      3
2 b     NA             NA
3 c     2017-05-01     45
```

I want it to return a table with values indicating the number of rows before and including the first row with a non-zero, not the value of the first non-zero, as in the table above:

I.e. For site 'a', we had to survey 4 months(rows) to record our focal species for the first time, site 'b' recorded the focal species during the 1st survey, and site 'c' recorded the focal species on the 5th survey.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  site  Date       values
  <fct> <date>      <dbl>
1 a     2017-04-01      4
2 b     2017-01-01      1
3 c     2017-05-01      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(values != 0) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
> # Groups:   site [3]
>   site  Date       values     n
>   <chr> <date>      <dbl> <int>
> 1 a     2017-04-01      3     4
> 2 b     2017-01-01     10     1
> 3 c     2017-05-01     45     5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose than Jaap. First, I define a function that counts leading zeroes and adds one. It uses the `rle` (Run Length Encoding) function.

```
count0 <- function(x){
  tmp <- rle(x)
  ifelse(!tmp$values[1], tmp$lengths[1] + 1, 1)
}
```

Here, I find the date of the first non-zero element, then I apply `count0` to count leading zeroes.

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  summarise(Date = Date[(values>0)][1],                          
            values = count0(values))
```

This gives the required output.

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   site  Date       values
#   <chr> <date>      <dbl>
# 1 a     2017-04-01      4
# 2 b     2017-01-01      1
# 3 c     2017-05-01      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` possibility:

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(val = ifelse((values != 0 & lag(values, default = 0) == 0) | values == 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  summarise(Date = first(Date[values != 0]),
            values = sum(val))
```